# ReactJS Google Recaptcaha errors due to dynamic iframe

Tags: iframe, reactjs, recaptcha

Question more for documentation because React does not document this behaviour.

ReactJS throws an error, stopping execution of JS before ComponentDidMount() of:

```
Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot ...
```

Which is caused by having an element with content that is different between rendering serverside and clientside.
This could be caused by such as the following snippet from Google Recaptcha where the content of the iFrame changes every request:

```
   var MyForm = React.createClass({
...
     render: function() {
       return (
         <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=SECRETKEY"
                 frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"
                 style={{width: "302px", height: "422px", borderStyle: "none"}} >
          </iframe>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to dangerously set the iframe as inner html so that react doesn't compare the rendered versions.

```
renderNoscriptCaptcha: function() {
if(!this.state.isBrowser) {
  return {__html:
  '<div style="width: 302px; height: 482px; line-height: 0">\
     <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=SECRETKEY" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height: 422px; border-style: none" >\
     </iframe>\
     <div style="height: 60px; border-style: none; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px">\
       <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; resize: none; line-height: 24px; font-size: 11px" >\
       </textarea>\
     </div>\
   </div>'
    }
  }
},

render: function() {
   return (
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderNoscriptCaptcha()}></div>
```